# Joint tail for Brownian motion $P[B_{t_1}>g_1,...,B_{t_n}>g_n]$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Maybe not surprisingly there seems to be a lack of in-depth study of sharp estimates for the joint tail of Brownian motion over different times

$$P[B_{t_1}>g_1,...,B_{t_n}>g_n]$$

for strictly increasing times $0<R<t_1<t_2<...<t_n$ and $0<R<g_1<...<g_n$, where lets allow $R$ to be as large as we need to get a bound. There is a large literature on multivariate normal but I don't think there are any in-depth articles on the joint-tail for Brownian motion (if I missed it, please let me know). Using the prop.3.1 in ["On multivariate Gaussian tails"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02517804), I was able to get a bound for my setting.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left[B_{t_{1}}\geq g_{1},...,B_{t_{n}}\geq g_{n}\right] \leq &  (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n}(t_{i+1}-t_{i})\right)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{t_{1}}{g_{1}}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \frac{t_{i+1}-t_{i}}{g_{i+1}-g_{i}}\right)^{-1}\cdot\exp\left( - \frac 1 2 \left(\frac{g_{1}^{2}}{t_{1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(g_{i+1}-g_{i})^{2}}{t_{i+1}-t_{i}} \right)\right),
\end{align}
for $t_{0}=0$. (Also see example 4 in "Asymptotics and Bounds for
Multivariate Gaussian Tails").  But given the ubiquitousness of Brownian motion, I thought it would be interesting to ask and post this as a semi-open problem to possibly get sharper estimates than the one above.

Here are some approaches for possibly sharper bounds:

1)In prop.3.1 in ["On multivariate Gaussian tails"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02517804), one of the bounds involves the maximal eigenvalue for the covariance matrix. So a promising route is getting a sharp estimates on that eigenvalue. As mentioned here [Maximum eigenvalue of a covariance matrix of Brownian motion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366339/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-covariance-matrix-of-brownian-motion), this is a non-trivial problem.

2)One could try to do it by hand via the Chapman-Kolmogorov and then successively splitting
intervals, but the estimates get messy quick.

3)By writing this event as $P[\max (B_{t_k}/g_k)\leq-1]$ and for $g_{k}=at_{k}$ (where the Savage (1962)-condition fails), I followed the
"Survival probabilities of weighted random walks". Here I came across having to get sharp upper/lower bounds on the density of the running maximum of Brownian motion with drift.